# Does altering a column will lock the table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, locking, ddl

Need help figuring this out. Tried googling, but found no specific answer.

Does altering a table in PostgreSQL like this will lock the table?

```
ALTER TABLE public.account ALTER COLUMN type acc_type VARCHAR(16) USING acc_type::VARCHAR(16);
```

Comment: Don't randomly google. Read the manual. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#id-1.9.3.35.5) "*An ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock is held unless explicitly noted*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that has to take an access exclusive lock, because the metadata change. Depending on what data type it was before that would be a very fast operation (e. g., it was `varchar(10)` before) or a very slow operation (if the previous type is not binary compatible).

Comment: Actually now it s varchar(16) and will be varchar(32), so I assume it will be a fast operation, but still it will lock the table yes?

Comment: Yes, precisely. This will only be a problem if you have long running transactions (which are evil anyway).

Comment: Is there a rough estimate on what 'very fast' actually would be? ms/s/m/h? What's the fastest and slowest operations you've seen for altering a column type in your experience?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary If no table rewrite is necessary, I would be surprised if it took more than a few milliseconds (unless the operation is blocked by a lock).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Your answers are always amazing on anything Postgres, thank you for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe if I alter a column from not null to nullable, how long will that operation take?

Comment: @manh.vu That is instantaneous.